# Select and order records in one to many relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

Consider the following tables:

```
Student
-------
id
name
```

and

```
Assignment
----------
id
name
```

and

```
Grade
-----
id
student_id
assignment_id
grade
```

A student can have multiple grades, corresponding to different assignments.

Now, I want to select records to generate a table that looks like this:

```
Name      Assignment 1      Assignment 2    Assignment 3
--------------------------------------------------------
Bob       55%               80%             23%
Suzy      90%               65%             100%
```

And, I want to be able to sort by one of the grades (i.e. Assignment 1)

Is this something which can be done with SQL? As an added bonus, can this be done with flask-sqlalchemy?

I have an idea I need to do a JOIN and ORDER BY but I don't really know where to go with this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQLite, you have to use the lowest common denominator of SQL, meaning a join for every single assignment you want to consider:

```
SELECT
  name,
  Grade1.grade AS assignment1,
  Grade2.grade AS assignment2,
  Grade3.grade AS assignment3
FROM
  Student
  LEFT JOIN Grade AS Grade1 ON (Student.id = Grade1.student_id and Grade1.assignment_id = ...)
  LEFT JOIN Grade AS Grade2 ON (Student.id = Grade2.student_id and Grade2.assignment_id = ...)
  LEFT JOIN Grade AS Grade3 ON (Student.id = Grade3.student_id and Grade3.assignment_id = ...)
ORDER BY Grade1.grade
```

Translating this to SQLAlchemy should be straightforward.

Comment: Thanks @univerio! I am taking this sort of approach and it seems to be working so far

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you may consider something like this

```
with
  tab as(
    select s.name as student, a.name as assignment, g.v as grade
      from grade g
           inner join student s on g.s_n = s.n
           inner join assignment a on g.a_n = a.n
  )
select * 
  from tab
  pivot (min(grade) for assignment in ('Assignment 1', 'Assignment 2', 'Assignment 3'))
order by 2, 3 desc, 7
```

Comment: @ian93 Do you mind not making us guess what database you are using?

Comment: Sorry -- I'm using SQLite but I'm really looking for a sqlalchemy solution!

Comment: @ian93 Any "sqlalchemy solution" depends on what SQL you want to write. Just because you are using SQLAlchemy does not mean you can ignore the underlying database.